# Why does the std::scope_success destructor check if uncaught exceptions are less or equal

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, raii

According to

[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_success/~scope_success](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_success/%7Escope_success)

The destructor of `std::scope_success` checks if the current number of uncaught exception (std::uncaught_exceptions) is *less or equal* than when it was constructed.

It makes sense that it compares it to the previous value (on its construction) instead of zero, so that `scope_success` can be used during stack unwinding.

But why does it check if the count is less or equal, and not just equal? Is there a situation where `std::uncaught_exceptions` will be lower in its destructor, than in its constructor?

Comment: It is a moveable object so you could create it during unwinding, move it to some storage and destroy it later with totally unrelated count value. But that makes the comparison meaningless so that usecase likely does not make sense at all.